# How can I start live streaming using RTMP link from iPhone using Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, rtmp, live-streaming

I'm working on a project in which users can go for live stream using iPhone device camera.
I looked for the same and found certain libraries but mostly are paid.
So, please suggest the better way to achieve the desired result, any library link, blog or code would be helpful.

The project is built using swift 5, Xocde 12.3.

Reference link:

I found this library for android: https://github.com/TakuSemba/RtmpPublisher

Thanks in advance.

#HappyCoding

Answer (score 2):

try this

"Camera and Microphone streaming library via RTMP, HLS for iOS, macOS, tvOS."
https://github.com/shogo4405/HaishinKit.swift

Comment: Please add some details on how this specifically solves the issue.

Comment: @de. author asked: "How can I start live streaming using RTMP link from iPhone using Swift 5; ...which users can go for live stream using iPhone device camera...". Library description: ""Camera and Microphone streaming library via RTMP, HLS for iOS, macOS, tvOS." https://github.com/shogo4405/HaishinKit.swift#rtmp-usage. The library allows you to stream to RTPM server. I don't understand what details should I add to my answer?